# Fail to use Not Like in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this Query.

```
SELECT
Distinct
   CASE CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL)
       WHEN 0 THEN SessionURL 
       ELSE LEFT(SessionURL, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) - 1) END AS VisitPage , count(*) as [VisitTime] 
FROM VistedURL
```

Its gives following result.

```
         VisitPage               VisitTime
  a/default.aspx                    99
  a/home.aspx                       15
  a/admin/dashboard.aspx            05
  a/contactus.aspx                  54
  a/admin/login.aspx                10
```

I want to use `Not Like` in above query.means:

`WHERE SessionURL NOT LIKE '%admin%'`

And remove the 3rd and 5th data of above result table which contain `admin`.But unable to use `Not Like` in above query.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that query is the query that works? It's missing a `GROUP BY` which is normally a hard error in SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to use..." - do you get an error? Incorrect results?

Comment: Ya I am missing group by.copy and paste mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CASE CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL)        
      WHEN 0 THEN SessionURL         
   ELSE LEFT(SessionURL, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) - 1) END AS VisitPage , count(1) as [VisitTime]  
  FROM VistedURL
  GROUP BY SessionURL WHERE SessionURL NOT LIKE '%admin%'
```

Please try the above query. <strike>Also just `count(1)` is better than `count(*)`</strike>

Comment: `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` produce the **exact** same query plan - there's **no difference** at all .....

Comment: You are right. updated the answer appropriately. http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2008/12/debunking-myth-select-count-vs-select.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) = 0 THEN SessionURL         
   ELSE LEFT(SessionURL, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) - 1) END AS VisitPage, 
   count(1) as [VisitTime]  
   FROM VistedURL
   WHERE SessionURL NOT LIKE '%admin%'
   GROUP BY SessionURL
```